# gregorian calendar java error

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I can't print GregorianCalendar

```
    package Tests;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Data 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar(1999, 2, 2);
        System.out.println(time);
    }

}
```

I receive this

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Belgrade",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=119,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Belgrade,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=?,YEAR=1999,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=?,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]

How I can print it?

Comment: check SimpleDateFormat (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this like :-

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
Date now = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(now);
```

or

```
Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(2010, 9, 26);  // allocate with the specified date
cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);                      // 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday)
```

Comment: But why I can't use it in simply way? Just print on reference "time"?

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern solution uses the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class instead. Avoid `GregorianCalendar` as it is now obsolete.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1999 , Month.FEBRUARY , 2 ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 1999-02-02

The `toString` method uses the standard ISO 8601 formats. For other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow for more examples and discussion, as that has beeen covered many many times.

Generally best to let `DateTimeFormatter` automatically localize for you.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> mardi 2 février 1999

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

when you call

```
System.out.println(time)
```

you've actually calling the toString() method of the Calendar instance (in this case, a GregorianCalendar one)

In order to have a properly formatted date, use **SimpleDateFormat** as stated in the Javadoc

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html